# error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char' [-fpermissive] strcat(encrypted, key[i]);

Tags: c++

Why the strcat() function not working. The error is the invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char'. Why the error is showing const char. I have not declared any array as const.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  cout<<"Enter the secret message"<<endl;
  char secret[80]{};//Initialising leads to removal of garbage values
  cin.getline(secret,80);
  char alphabet[] {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
  char key[] {"XZNLWEBGJHQDYVTKFUOMPCIASRxznlwebgjhqdyvtkfuompciasr"};
  int i{};
  char encrypted[80] {};
  char decrypted[80] {};

  for(auto val:secret){
    i=0;
    while(i<strlen(alphabet) && val!=alphabet[i]){
      i++;
    }
    if(i<strlen(alphabet))
      strcat(encrypted, key[i]);
    else
      strcat(encrypted, val);
  }
  cout<<"Encrypting..."<<endl;
  cout<<"Encrypted value: "<<encrypted;

  for(auto val: encrypted){
    i=0;
    while(i<strlen(encrypted) && val!=encrypted[i])
      i++;
    if(i<strlen(encrypted))
      strcat(decrypted, alphabet[i]);
    else
      strcat(decrypted, val);
  }
  cout<<"Decrypting: "<<endl;
  cout<<"Decrypted value: "<<decrypted<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The second argument of `strcat` has to be a string, not a `char`.

Comment: Why are you using character arrays and C string functions in C++ when you have `std::string`?

Comment: Post the actual error message.

Comment: Can anyone explain about char* and const char*? I just wanted to try c-style strings @Someprogrammerdude.

Comment: Your title says "`invalid conversion from char to const char`". I'd be willing to bet that the actual message is "`invalid conversion from char* to const char*`". You need to include the exact copy-and-pasted error message in the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

The `strcat` function concatenates one string onto another. But `key[i]` is not a string.

Comment: how can I concatenate the key[i] using C-style string.

Comment: I just wouldn't use C-style strings. But if you must, just write a function that does what you want and call it.